# How to append child to an ancestor into the clone using range selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to store 2 versions of 'start' div, so I'm making a clone and trying to append 'span' to an ancestor into the clone, but it' crashing.  How can I attain my goal?

```js
function Func() {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if (sel.toString().length != 0 && sel.getRangeAt) {
    se = $('<span style="background-color: #3366CC;" id="NewLink">')[0];
    var rng = sel.getRangeAt(sel.rangeCount - 1);
    var anc = rng.commonAncestorContainer;
    alert("the ancestor of selection is " + anc.textContent);
    rng.surroundContents(se);

    var temp = document.getElementById("start");
    var cl = temp.cloneNode(true);

    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = sel.toString();
    alert("trying to append child with your selection text to an ancestor into the clone");
    try {
      cl.querySelector(anc).appendChild(span);
      alert(cl.outerHTML);
    } catch (l) {
      alert('Oops it seems something goes wrong');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
try to select the text below
<div id="start" onmouseup="Func ()">
  <div id="second">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>
      best things are free...
    </p>
    <p>
      long text ....
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're including jQuery why aren't you using it?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, Is it not jQuery se = $('<span style="background-color: #3366CC;" id="NewLink">')[0];?